# Adapter notifyDataSetChanged only working when postDelayed

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a custom base adapter for a ListActivty. I'm trying to update the list after any item is clicked, this is my onListItemClick code:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String pkg = mAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
    boolean isProtected = ApplicationUtils.isPackageProtected(this, pkg) != null;
    PreferenceUtils.setPreference(mContext, null, pkg, !isProtected, false);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

However, notifyDataSetChanged doesn't updates the list views. As a workaround I fou

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String pkg = mAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
    boolean isProtected = ApplicationUtils.isPackageProtected(this, pkg) != null;
    PreferenceUtils.setPreference(mContext, null, pkg, !isProtected, false);
    Handler adapterHandler = new Handler();
    adapterHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Can someone explain me why does this happens and tell me if is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on a sample code I'm using. I fixed it. Check the last comments on [this](http://gist.github.com/romannurik/2980593) gist for more info, and [this](http://gist.github.com/D4rKn3sSyS/6057805) gist for the fix